# Raid - Выбор HDD для NAS

Tags: hdd, raid

Доброго времени суток!

Не так давно потребовалось обзавестись NAS-сервером для обеспечения облачного хранилища. Выбор пал на Synology DS411 Slim, в котором 4 HDD макс. по 1 Тб каждый объединяются в RAID5 (RAID1 + RAID0 не рассматриваю, это и так понятно).

Собственно, сам сервер выбрал. Осталось выбрать жесткий диск. И, если обзоры на продукцию Synology можно найти очень часто, то обзоры на производителей хардов не так-то просто.

Собственно, вопрос: какой хард выбрать для NAS-сервака емкостью 1 Тб? Некоторые советовали выбрать WD Red, но, прочитав пару мнений о нем (да и послушав тоже), понял, что вещь некачественная и частенько выходит из строя (высокий процент отказа).

Помогите с выбором. Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2):

На протяжении нескольких лет наименьший процент отказов у Hitachi и Toshiba плюс 5-летняя гарантия изготовителя. Но статистика штука тонкая. У мну сигейты подохли, заказал тошибу 3Tb.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, как можно не найти у производителя описание какие харды для чего созданы... 
Пользуюсь Seagate постоянно уже много лет. Да, бывает, что попадаются определенные партии с косяками... Можно вспомнить и IBM DTLA серию - это для статистики...
Но о главном. Seagate:
3,5`
 1. ES - серверные диски общего назначения;
 2. SV35 - диски для хранения видео и видеорегистраторов;
 3. и т.д.

В общем, вам [сюда](http://www.seagate.com/ru/ru/internal-hard-drives/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.Я знаю про эту страницу и знаю, где найти про назначение каждых дисков, например, WD Red - специально для NAS-серверов, WD Green - энергосберегающие (так же подходят для серверов) и т.д.Вопрос, ведь, не в том совсем. А в том, какие из них надежнее. Я, конечно, понимаю, что бэкапы и все такое (я не забыл про них :)), но хотелось бы, чтобы необходимость в них возникала как можно реже.

Comment: При такой постановке вопроса получим ответ в стиле "всяк кулик свое болото хвалит". Это примерно, как спросить какой проц лучше Intel  или AMD...  Потом, еще непонятно каков сервер, может он вообще под SAS-диски. Правда ведь?  HP, например, ставит на сервера Seagate, Lenovo, в основном, тоже (как на ноуты, так и на компы)...  Вот и выбирайте...

Answer (score 1):

Вокруг все хорошо отзываются о WD Black. При этом серию red тоже недолюбливают. У меня хитачи очень часто подводили (это к предыдущему ответу), про тошибу ничего не скажу.

Comment: От WD-шек отказался в пользу Hitachi и Toshiba - WD в последние год-полтора сыпливые стали...(

Comment: @Zerglyn не подводили :) меня во всяком случае. Ну и ближайшее окружение. Хотя за самые последние я ручаться не могу.